# Problem with negative radius for ST_Buffer

Tags: postgis

I am very new to PostGis and I am trying to use negative radius of buffer for `ST_Buffer` function.

The column is `geometry(MultiPolygon, 4326)` imported from a shapefile. Positive radius for `ST_Buffer` works:

(`select  ST_AsGeoJSON(geom) as no_buffer, ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_buffer(geom, 1)) as buffer from sections`)

[image]

However, when I user negative radius, e.g. -1 I get:

`ERROR: lwgeom_free called with unknown type (105) Invalid type
SQL state: XX000`

I am sure it is some kind of noob question, but I couln't find the solution using google and StackExchange archive.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Try with only one entry and then another, or subsets of your data to see if particular values are triggering it. Eg. perhaps it can't handle multipolygons that would reduce to 0 area.

Comment: also bear in mind that buffering by -1 degrees would make quite a few smaller countries disappear. This may cause problems with EMPTY geometries which might explain this message. Try a smaller buffer size like -0.001 or -0.01

Comment: It could also convert a single-part polygon to a multi-part polygon, or collapse a polygon to a line..

Comment: @StevenKay you hit the nail! the polygons are really small so 1 degree was too much. When I reduce the number it works :) (Stupid me for not trying...) Please add it as answer.

Comment: Which version of PostGIS are you using.  In newer that should be spitting out the invalid geometry type name instead of the number.

Comment: postgis 2.2.0 but Steven's comment solved my problem